Detached Ramp For 10 x12 shed
I’m extremely new to wood working so please bear with me.
I’m trying to build a shed ramp that’s 4 ft long and 59 inches wide. I’m only using 2 by 6 pressure treated lumber. I’m trying to determine how to cut the stringers but it’s very confusing to me.
I was going to attach the ramp to the shed using a ledger board but I decided to build a detached ramp instead. The ramp needs to support my riding mower.
Any assistance on the easiest way to do this would be appreciated.
To answer some of the comments:

I do own the essential power tools including table saw and circular saw.
I’d say the shed floor is about 10-11 inches above the grade of the shed.
I have tried to research this through Google and YouTube, but unfortunately, I'm still confused. As i mentioned, I’m not very handy but I try. I’m most confused on cutting the stringers. I think once I get past that part, I’ll be good.



Welcome to WSE.  In order to help we could use a bit more information How high above the grade is the floor of the shed and what is the construction of the floor?  Is the area in front of the door dirt/grass or pavement? IS the area in front of the door level or sloped and if so, how much.  If you can make a section cut that shows the situation at the general sill that would help.  In addition, what tools do you have, like a circle or table saw etc.?  The more info you can give us, the better we can help.

Hi, welcome to Woodworking! Before we get to concrete aspects of your project, how much research did you do before asking? It's not clear if you did any because nothing is mentioned in the body text. The SE model doesn't just for prior research, it requires a good-faith attempt to find the solution for yourself, and only if that is unsuccessful, or you're left with some specific detail that needs clarification, do you ask a Question here.

Now to your ramp, it only needs to withstand the weight of a ride-on mower (plus adult presumably) so the strength requirement is not at all a big stretch for the only stated material — 2x6s. I can't imagine any reasonably design, that transfers weight to the ground as needed, that wouldn't be strong enough.... simple ramps like this can easily be built strongly enough to support oversize American pickups, so even if the adult driver is north of say 300lb it just doesn't add enough weight to be significant.

P.S. A picture is worth a thousand words. If you return to give us the details asked by @Ashlar, please add a drawing. Even the most basic sketch can help!

I updated my post so hopefully that helps.

Are you asking what shape the stringers should be, or how to safely cut them into that shape? (Or both?)

I would say both to be safe. I feel like I have the shape as of yesterday but could be wrong.

*sigh* Have you looked at How To Build a Ramp for a Shed on Family Handyman? How about Shed Ramp on Instructables? How to Build Ramps, Steps, and Custom Doors for a DIY Shed on Just Measuring up? How To Build A Shed Ramp from Guy of All Trades on YT? How to Build a Ramp for a Shed in Less Than a Day on Popular Woodworking? How to Build a Shed Ramp on One Project Closer?

So those examples that i saw involve mounting the ledger board to the shed. My question is, do you think there is enough wood below the shed for a 2 by 6 ledger board to be mounted? I had a ledger board mounted before but it seemed to be pretty low on the wood (don't know the proper term - sorry) and I was concerned about it not being stable and it breaking off the shed when a lot of weight would be placed on it (such as a riding mower). Hopefully that made sense.

@Graphus - you think lag screws would work?
